# Perl -- unable to construct array of objects

Tags: arrays, perl, ref

I've tried two similar bits of syntax. This first one works:

```
   my $obj = PI::something::ObjectManipulator->new();
   $obj->setValue('HELLO');
   my $objList = [$object];
```

This, however, doesn't:

```
  my $objList= [];
  foreach my $value (@values) {
    my $obj = PI::something::ObjectManipulator->new();
    $obj->setValue($value);
    push @$objList, $obj;
  };
```

What is the difference between these two way of doing things? Why doesn't the second work? (By not work, it seems to be that $objList is still empty at the end of the code.)

Comment: Looks good from here. Are you sure that `@values` is not an empty list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `my $objList = [$object];` is a typo for `my $objList = [$obj];`, and assuming, `my @values = 'HELLO';`, there are no differences.

Assuming you meant "`@$objList` is still empty" when you said "`$objList` is still empty", that can only happen if the loop isn't entered (i.e. `@values` is empty).